# C Code build in RHEL7 and deployed in RHEL6, gdb is not working

Tags: c, gdb, proc, rhel7, rhel6

I am building my ProC code in RHEL7 and deploying it to RHEL6 server. It works fine, but I am not able to gdb properly. It says - "Single stepping until exit from function , which has no line number information."

If I deploy in RHEL7 server, I dont see this error and I can do line by line gdb.

When gdb run in deployed app in RHEL6:

```
$> gdb progname
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-92.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from progname...done.
(gdb) b progname.c:main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048fe8
(gdb) run arguments
Starting program: progname argments
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048fe8 in main ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.i686
(gdb) n
*Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.*
```

When gdb run in RHEL7 deployed app, we will see below results, which is expected in RHEL6 version as well

```
 $> gdb progname
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-100.el7_4.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from progname...done.
(gdb) b progname.c:main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048ff1: file progname.c, line 87.
(gdb) run arguments
Starting program: progname arguments
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=8, argv=0xffffbd14) at progname.c:87
87      progname.c: 
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-196.el7_4.2.i686 libgcc-4.8.5-16.el7_4.3.i686 libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.3.i686
(gdb) n
88      in /progname.c
```

Comment: The supported way to build executables that run on multiple versions of RHEL is to use the [Red Hat Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/7/html/user_guide/chap-Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset#sect-Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset-Compatibility). For maximum coverage, build on the lowest supported version (RHEL6.7 in the version cited in the link).

Answer (score 1):

> I am building my ProC code in RHEL7 and deploying it to RHEL6 server.

That only works by chance, and can break at any moment.

> I am not able to gdb properly

You are using older GDB on RHEL6, which probably doesn't understand some debug info created by RHEL7 compiler.

You could try building a new version of GDB on RHEL6, and use that.